# Can I use a different language wireless keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, wifi, macbook-pro, bluetooth

My Macbook pro is Japanese with a Japanese keyboard. I want to get a wireless bluetooth keyboard, but I am currently living in the UK and cannot get a wireless Japanese keyboard here. If I bought a US wireless keyboard, would this work with my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

You can get one on [eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xapple%20wireless%20keyboard%20japanese&_nkw=apple%20wireless%20keyboard%20japanese&_sacat=0), shipped from Hong Kong, for £34…

but yes, a US or UK one would work too - except the mapping would not be what you may be used to.

Though I may have a Japanese nickname;-) I've never actually used a Japanese keyboard, so I'm not sure what differences there may be in the layout.

Comment: Besides the layout differences, you'll also miss the designated "switch" keys that are pressed in order to go in and out of Japanese mode.  <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> toggles through each of your keyboards (such as English, Hiragana, Katakana)